# Why procedural models in Ursina are shaded differently

Tags: python, shader, light, ursina, panda3d

I can't figure out how to make Ursina procedural models look the same as mesh-based models.

```
from ursina import *
from ursina import shaders

app = Ursina()

L1 = DirectionalLight(color=color.white)
L1.setHpr((0, 0, 0))

e = Entity(model=Cube(), x=-2, color=color.green)
e = Entity(model='cube', x=2, color=color.red)

_ed = EditorCamera(rotation_speed = 200, panning_speed=200)

app.run()
```

Produces the following result:

Green and red cubes but green is black"

[image: Green and red cubes but green is black]

What am I missing? Why is the green cube not lit by the directional light?

I have tried using different shaders included in Ursina but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: I'd guess one has normals properly set up, the other doesn't.

Comment: You are correct, normals list was empty for the generated model. Calling e.model.generate_normals() helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a call to generate_normals() seems to fix the problem:

```
e = Entity(model=Cube(), x=-2, color=color.green)
e.model.generate_normals()
```